# How would I go about making a table with every combination of 2 values

Tags: lua, lua-table

So I'm just wondering, I want to make a table with every possible combination of two numbers kinda like

`t = { {x = 0, y = 0}, {x = 1, y = 2}}`

and so on, but how would I go about this?

Comment: Two nested for loops?

Comment: @Luatic I don't really get what you mean sorry, can you maybe try explaining it?

Comment: `for x = min_x, max_x do for y = min_y, max_y do table.insert(t, {x = x, y = y}) end end`